# Array Having null values

Tags: javascript, html

I need to copy all the drop down selected items to another drop down.

I don't know why it also copies a white space after every city name. 
Please tell me why.

```js
//var values;
// function to copy all the selected city name to //another drop box 
function copy_city_name(city) {
  var x = document.getElementById("new_list");
  //copy array values to any another variable(city_list)
  var city_list = city;
  //document.write(city);
  //ittration to copy all the name to another drop down    
  for (var i = 0; i <= city_list.length; i++) {
    var opt = city_list[i];
    var e1 = document.createElement("option");
    e1.textContent = opt;
    e1.value = opt;
    //alert(e1);
    //console.log(e1);
    x.add(e1);
  }
}
// function to select all the selected city name in a array.
function get_city_name() {
  // body...
  var fld = document.getElementById('city_name');
  // ittration to get names of all the selected city name. 
  for (var i = 0; i < fld.options.length; i++) {
    var values = [];
    if (fld.options[i].selected) {
      values.push(fld.options[i].value);
      copy_city_name(values); // passed all values to function 
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select multiple="multiple" name="city" id="city_name">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b"> B </option>
    <option value="c"> C</option>
    <option value="d"> D</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" onclick="get_city_name()">select multiple</button>
  <select multiple="multiple" name="get" id="new_list">
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: what is that `x.add(e1)`

Comment: I don't really get your question but if you just want to remove a trailing whitespace, use `string.trim()`

Comment: i *<=* city_list.length should be  i *<* city_list.length

Comment: hello sir, add is a function which help to assign any value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your `copy_city_name` function loop it must be `i < city_list.length;` not `i <= city_list.length;`

And in your `get_city_name` move `values` array outside of the loop to collect all selected options

```js
function copy_city_name(cities) {
  var list = document.getElementById("new_list");
  for (var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    var city = cities[i];
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.textContent = city;
    option.value = city;
    list.add(option);
  }
}
function get_city_name() {
  var fld = document.getElementById('city_name');
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < fld.options.length; i++) {
    if (fld.options[i].selected) {
      values.push(fld.options[i].value);
    }
  }

  copy_city_name(values);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select multiple="multiple" name="city" id="city_name">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b"> B </option>
    <option value="c"> C</option>
    <option value="d"> D</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" onclick="get_city_name()">select multiple</button>
  <select multiple="multiple" name="get" id="new_list">
  </select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. i *<=* city_list.length should be  i *<* city_list.length
2. you can shorten this using querySelector:

```js
// function to copy all the selected city name to another select
function copy_city_name() {
  var newList = document.getElementById("new_list"),
      opts = document.querySelectorAll('#city_name option:checked');
  // iteration to get names of all the selected city names. 
  for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
    var opt = document.createElement("option");
    opt.textContent = opts[i].textContent;
    opt.value = opts[i].value;
    newList.add(opt);
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select multiple="multiple" name="city" id="city_name">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b"> B </option>
    <option value="c"> C</option>
    <option value="d"> D</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" onclick="copy_city_name()">select multiple</button>
  <select multiple="multiple" name="get" id="new_list">
  </select>
</form>
```

If you want to move them, it is even shorter

```
for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
  newList.add(opts[i]);
}
```